# grep regex for file name with one separator but not two

Tags: bash, grep

So here's my problem, I have a script where I generate files like so (just an example):

`animal`

`animal.dog`

`animal.dog.7`

essentially this is a tree structure in files, each of which contain different information.

I'm trying to grab `animal.dog` but my regex `.*\..*$` wants to grab both

`animal.dog.7` and `animal.dog`

where I only want `animal.dog`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negated character class in `grep -E`  regex pattern:

```
^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

This will match `animal.dog` but won't match `animal.dog.7`

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^.]+`: Match 1+ characters that is not a DOT
- `\.`: Match a literal DOT
- `[^.]+`: Match 1+ characters that is not a DOT
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks very much! (I'll mark this the answer as soon as I can)